# How do I iterate through an array that uses a hashtable (Chord algorithm used)

Tags: java, arrays, p2p, chord

I am trying to implement the peer-to-peer chord algorithm. I make an array of nodes and each node has a fingertable. I need to be able to iterate through each fingertable (which is a hash table) to find where the key value is supposed to go. So basically I need my fingertable (hash table) to be able to be iterated through so I can find which node it goes to (which is in an array). I thought about putting each fingertable (hash table) into an array list, but I was not able to get it to work.

This may not be the right way to go about making chord work efficiently. So if there is an easier way of making this work, please let me know. Also, this does not need to be the full chord algorithm (where nodes need to be added and removed and all that jazz). Just a very basic version of chord.

```
package chord;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Hashtable;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Chord {
    private int userIDSpaceB;
    private int userNumberOfNodesN;

    private int randomKeyID;
    private int nodeStart;

    private int[] nodes;

    private Random randomKeyInt;
    private int idSpace;


    public int answer = 0;
    /**
     * Chord constructor
     * 
     * @param idSpace
     *            - the space the user wants to use (B). 2^B
     * @param numberOfNodes
     *            - the number of nodes the user wants to have
     */
    public Chord(int idSpace, int numberOfNodes) {
        this.userIDSpaceB = idSpace;
        this.idSpace = idSpace;
        this.userNumberOfNodesN = numberOfNodes;
        generateNumbers();
    }

    /**
     * Generates random numbers, assigns node list, creates fingers.
     */
    public void generateNumbers() {
        // Get int 2^B
        userIDSpaceB = (int) Math.pow(2, userIDSpaceB);
        System.out.println("B (Circular ID Space): " + userIDSpaceB);
        System.out.println("Number of Nodes: " + userNumberOfNodesN);
        // Create node array and makes sure there is no duplicates
        nodes = new int[userNumberOfNodesN];
        // This loops through and makes the appropriate amount of numbers to
        // choose from
        ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        for (int i = 1; i < userIDSpaceB; i++) {
            list.add(new Integer(i));
        }
        // This will shuffle the list then nodes will be assigned a number
        Collections.shuffle(list);
        for (int i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++) {
            nodes[i] = list.get(i);
        }
        // Sorts nodes from least to greatest
        Arrays.sort(nodes);

        System.out.println("Nodes array: " + Arrays.toString(nodes));

        // Get key value
        randomKeyInt = new Random();
        randomKeyID = randomKeyInt.nextInt(userIDSpaceB + 1) + 1;
        System.out.println("Key ID: " + randomKeyID);
        nodeStart = nodes[1];
        System.out.println("Node Start: " + nodeStart);

        // Create successor and predecessor hashtables
        Hashtable<Integer, Integer> successor = new Hashtable<Integer, Integer>();
        Hashtable<Integer, Integer> predecessor = new Hashtable<Integer, Integer>();

        // Set this to 1 because you are trying to get the succesor.
        // Onces j exceeds the length of the node array, set it back to zero
        // because
        // The last element in the node array has the successor of nodes[0]
        System.out.println("\nSuccessors of Nodes:");
        int j = 1;
        for (int i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++) {
            if (j > nodes.length - 1) {
                j = 0;
            }
            successor.put(nodes[i], nodes[j]);
            System.out.println("N" + nodes[i] + " successor is " + nodes[j] + ".");
            j++;
        }
        // Set m to the last element of nodes array because that is
        // nodes[0]'s
        // predecessor
        // After that first iteration, set m = 0 because that will fill all
        // of
        // the right predecessors
        System.out.println("\nPredeccessors of Nodes:");
        int m = nodes.length - 1;
        for (int i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++) {
            if (m > nodes.length - 1) {
                m = 0;
            }
            predecessor.put(nodes[i], nodes[m]);
            System.out.println("N" + nodes[i] + " predecessor is " + nodes[m] + ".");
            m++;
        }
////////// This is where I would create the arraylist of finger nodes////////////
        // Create finger table for each node
        for (int i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++) {
            System.out.println("\n");
            fingerTable(nodes[i]);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Creates finger table for a given node
     * 
     * @param node
     *            - the node that a finger table will be created for
     * @return 
     */
    public Hashtable<Integer, Integer> fingerTable(int node) {
        int individualNode = node;
        // Create finger table
        Hashtable<Integer, Integer> fingerTable = new Hashtable<Integer, Integer>();
        // This would create one single finger table
        int[] finger = new int[idSpace];
        for (int i = 0; i < finger.length; i++) {
            int temp = (int) ((int) (individualNode) + Math.pow(2, i));
            // If temp is greater than the userIdSpace you have to do
            // temp - userIdSpace
            // Ex: If finger = 68 but the max space is 64 (2^6) then you have to
            // do 68 - 64 = 4 which is the correct finger.
            // Then find the closest node to it
            if (temp > userIDSpaceB) {
                temp = temp - userIDSpaceB;
            }
            finger[i] = temp;
        }
        // T is your index keeper for finger array.
        int t = 0;
        for (int i = 0; t < finger.length;) {
            // If finger is greater than last node, then it has to go to the
            // first node.
            if (finger[t] > nodes[nodes.length - 1]) {
                fingerTable.put(finger[t], nodes[0]);
                i = 0;
                t++;
            }
            // If the finger array number is greater, then increment i for
            // finger array
            else if (finger[t] > nodes[i]) {
                i++;
            }
            // If finger node is less than or equal to a the node then assign
            // it.
            else if (finger[t] <= nodes[i]) {
                fingerTable.put(finger[t], nodes[i]);
                i = 0;
                t++;
            }
        }
        // Prints finger table for each node.
        System.out.println("Finger Table for node: N" + individualNode);
        for (int i = 0; i < finger.length; i++) {
            System.out.println("N" + individualNode + " + " + ((int) Math.pow(2, i)) + " = "
                    + (int) ((int) (individualNode) + Math.pow(2, i)) + " Hashed Node = N"
                    + fingerTable.get(finger[i]));
        }
        return fingerTable;
    }

    /**
     * Runs app.
     * 
     * @param args
     *            - not used
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter a Circular ID Space (5 <= number <= 10)");
        int userIDSpace = scan.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Enter number of nodes to be in Chord system (5 <= number <= 15)");
        int userNumberOfNodes = scan.nextInt();
        scan.close();
        new Chord(userIDSpace, userNumberOfNodes);
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on another site in the Stack Exchange network: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: It looks as if that is a peer review site. For code that is complete and running, but can be made to run more efficiently. This code is not complete. It is missing a major chunk of code. So I'm wondering why it should be changed to that website? Thanks

Comment: Then, [edit] your question and provide current vs. desired behaviour. As currently written, the question  asks for more efficient or _easier way of making this work_…

Comment: "So basically I need my fingertable (hash table) to be able to be iterated through so I can find which node it goes to (which is in an array). I thought about putting each fingertable (hash table) into an array list, but I was not able to get it to work."  is what I'm needing... I added the second paragraph because I'm sure there is a better way of coding it, and also to explain that it does not need to be a full chord algorithm. I will gladly delete the second paragraph if it causes confusion.

Comment: @JosefZ OP is correct, [codereview.se] is not for bug-hunting - this question would get closed as "broken code" on CR. Please read the [Guide to CR for SO users](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/q/5777/23788). The question is off-topic not because it belongs on CR, but because *Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself.* See [MCVE].

Comment: Again: please [edit] your question and provide current vs. desired behaviour. "_…  I was not able to get it to work_" does not appear to be a good symptom description. @Mat'sMug indeed: mea culpa.

Comment: I would gladly edit my question, but then I would have to explain the chord algorithm in it. This question is aimed for people who have experience with the chord algorithm. If you know what it is, then you will know that you get a key value and that key value goes to a specific node. To find that node, you have to iterate through the finger tables (which is my question of how to iterate through them). So once again, the people who deal with the chord algorithm will know exactly what I need. I would hate to bother someone and make them learn chord whenever I'm sure there are people on this site

Comment: That already know it like the back of their hand.

Comment: I'm honestly confused by this whole debate. I don't have any bugs with my code. My code is 100% runnable. I'm trying to accomplish something new with my code. My question is how to iterate through my fingertable that I have created. Each node has a fingertable. Before either of you comment again, can you just answer this one question: Do you or do you not know specifically what the chord algorithm is? If not, then I can see how this question is not specific. But if you do know, then I cannot see how this question is not specific. I literally have everything except being able to iterate through

Comment: the fingertable. Therefore I cannot complete the chord algorithm. So I need something new with my code.

Comment: @Mat'sMug 
So is there a problem with my question or not? Is this the wrong way to ask a question on this site or was this just not the right question for you both? Please answer so I know in the future, thanks.

Comment: It's way too much code to sift through! =) people that know the answer to your question aren't very likely to spend half an hour looking at all that. Best narrow it down, focus on the *specific* part that's missing/broken, explain *specifically* what's not working, and describe a bit of what you've attempted too - the [ask] page has all the details. Good luck!

Comment: Perfect, thank you for your help.